# Save Beautiful Soup Output to JSON

Tags: python

I have a loop that I am not sure how to close so I can save the output locally as json. My print output looks fine but I am just getting the last line of my output on my json save with the following:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.website.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
html = webpage.decode('utf8')
type(html)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlsoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
type(htmlsoup)

enter code hereanchors = htmlsoup.find_all('a')
type(anchors)

for a in anchors:
 print(a.text)

filename = 'website.json'

import json
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(a.text, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Currently you loop over a(nchor) in anchors and then just print the last anchor. In other languages a would be out of scope because it is declared in the for loop, but python allows it. a.text is really just the last anchor.
What type is anchors? You can try writing anchors directly to file.

Comment: I am, I just need everything at anchor a. Munging it, then storing to a datagram will be much easier.